# How to define custom area using Google Maps API and Java

Tags: java, google-maps

I'm trying to build an application with Java where I need to define some custom areas which are not readily available (e.g. jurisdictions for different police stations or fire stations in a city). My goal is to find out that, given an user's location, which jurisdiction that is a part of. I tried the Google Maps API, but couldn't find a solution.

Can anyone please help me find the solution using Google Maps API or any other API.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [PolyUtil.containsLocation(LatLng point, List polygon, boolean geodesic)](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L98) from Android-map-utils

That given the list of latitude and longitude that defines your custom areas you can check if current location is inside or not.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I was trying to find something which will be platform independent. I would like to put this logic in some server side platform independent language like Java, so that if I want to publish my App on IoS, I don't have to rewrite the logic there.